# OneSignal issue on Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

On android, i added One Signal plugin on my app and i added this code on the `platform.ready` section

```
window["plugins"].OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 6, visualLevel: 6});
  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  };

  window["plugins"].OneSignal
    .startInit("******-****-****-****-***********", "**********")
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .endInit();
```

as i launch the app it shows a bunch of alerts sending requests to onesignal and the app suddenly closes and onesignal doesn't detect any subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

I used this tutorial for adding onesignal to my Ionic3 app and I don't have errors or problems, maybe you can check it :)

https://medium.com/appseed-io/how-to-integrate-onesignal-push-notifications-into-an-ionic-3-application-eb2fdc3e6176

With this guide you don't need to edit something in platform.ready, but only in Ionic code!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Followed the guide you gave me but the app still behaves the way it used to do ... :/

Comment: I tested on another device and it added a subscriber but the app still crashes

Answer (score 0):

This is my plugin list

```
cordova-admob-sdk 0.17.0 "AdMob SDK"
cordova-plugin-admob-free 0.17.0 "Cordova AdMob Plugin"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 2.1.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.1 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-promise-polyfill 0.0.2 "cordova-promise-polyfill"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.4.1 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

You think there could be some malfunctioning between two plugins ?